# Accessing jQuery object in JADE

Tags: node.js, haml, express, pug

During login, I save the userId in a jQuery cookie, so that I can access it by `$.cookie('userId')`.

Now that I am trying to access it from Jade, as,

```
- if ($.cookie('userId') === userId)
```

I get an error

> $ is not defined

How can I access the cookie ?

My code:

```
- if (($.cookie('userId')) === userId)
                                                input(type='submit', value='Move')
                                            else
                                                input(type='submit', disabled, value='Move'')
```

Answer (score 14):

You seem to misunderstand concepts. Let me give you a lecture. ;)

**Basics.** Cookie is stored on the client-side. So using jQuery `$.cookie('userId')` will retrieve it when this script is run on the client-side.

But here you use JADE templating engine on server-side. So you didn't even send the page to the client-side yet. So what cookie do you want to retrieve? There is no cookie, because you are at the server.

There's more. Running `$.cookie('userId')` throws the error, because you are on the server-side. There is no `$` object. And there cannot be, because you cannot use jQuery on server-side (well, actually you can, but this is irrelevant at the moment). Did you define `$` object in your route system? Or did you define helper `$`? I don't think so.

**Express+JADE tutorial.** Now let me give you a short tutorial. Say you have a view (in `app.js`)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.jade', { code: 500 });
});
```

Now in `index.jade` you can use `code` as a variable. So you can write your `index.jade` for example like this:

```
// some code
- if (code == 500)
    input(type='submit', disabledm, value='Move')
- else
    input(type='submit', value='Move')
// some code
```

and now it will work! You may also use JavaScript functions in template if you predefine them. For example (in your `app.js`)

```
app.helpers({
    positive: function(no) { return no > 0; }
});
```

then in `index.jade` template you can use

```
- if (positive(-13))
    input(type="submit")
```

and even combine these two concepts

```
- if (positive(code))
    // do some stuff
```

**To cookie or not to cookie.** If you really need to use cookies (and you shouldn't except for sessions or CSRF for example) then you need to use client-side JavaScript. This means that you need to add (after jQuery)

```
script(src='my-path/my-script.js')
```

to the `index.jade` file and write `my-script.js` like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookie('userId') == userId) {
    // do something like append input to some holder
  }
});
```

But there are several problems with that solution. First: what is `userId` (second part of equality)? You need to predefine it in your `index.jade`. For example using

```
script
    var userId = #{ user.id };
```

and adding `user` object in your route. Second: cookies are local variables. Setting them requires additional server code which I do not thing you would like. This makes maintaining the app harder. And finally: storing a user's id in a cookie seems to be pointless. The final user don't even have to know it's own id. The server needs to know! Sessions system comes handy here.

**Final note.** The code you wrote shows us that you cannot distinguish between server-side and client-side JavaScript. The solution to your problem is to learn, learn and learn. Read tutorials and everything about JADE, Express and Node.js.

Comment: Thanks for all the points you mentioned. You are very right, I have messed up between client side and server side... That was the root problem. Thanks for pointing this out... great !

Answer (score 1):

What @freakish said is right. You're trying server side vs. client side.
If the cookie is set you should be able to access it on server like so

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   // index is jade template
   // local variable on jade template holds cookie value
   // use req.cookies.userid
   res.render('index', { userid: req.cookies.userid });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for req.cookies.userid. will try it whenever appropriate.